# How to change struts property using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp page which contains a set of number (cost), i would like to calculate a price depending on selected value.

It should be something like this:

```
<select ....  onChange="updateProperty();"/>
```

Here is my jsp page:

```
<s:select id="canBuylist" name="bundle" list="numberCanBuyList"/>
                <s:if test="flagPrice"> 
                    <s:property value="price"/> 
                    <s:text name="ooo.currency"/> 
                </s:if>

// this is my js function
       function updateProperty()
    {   
      the action property (value) = 5 * document.getElementById("canBuylist").value;
    }
```

Haw can i make this possible ?

Comment: What you mean by property ? do you want to calculate price and send it to server side ?

Comment: the price is an action class property, this property must be calculated depending on selected value * 5.
when user chose for example from my list 6 as value , this price must be displayed as 30 = 5 *6 .and then must be updated on server side

Comment: You can not set property value in JavaScript directly. If you are sending value as form submission than you can alter that HTML element value, or take hidden field that hold that value.

Comment: @YagneshAgola, thank you very much for your attention and support